# How to propagate the function definitions in one CMake target lib to the target links to it to resolve Undefined symbols error

Tags: c++, cmake, build, libraries

My project structure is

```
project/
  lib/
      CMakeLists.txt
      lib.cpp
      lib.h
      sublib/
          CMakeLists.txt
          sublib.h
          sublib.cpp
  test/
      CMakeLists.txt
      test.cpp # this must link to lib only, not lib and sublib
```

project/CMakeLists.txt

```
add_subdirectory(lib) 
add_subdirectory(test)
```

project/test/CMakeLists.txt

```
add_executable(test test.cpp)
add_test(test test)
target_link_libraries(
  test
  lib)
```

project/lib/CMakeLists.txt

```
add_subdirectory(sublib)

add_library(lib lib.cpp)
target_link_libraries(
  lib
  sublib)
```

project/lib/sublib/CMakeLists.txt

```
add_library(sublib sublib.cpp)
target_link_libraries(
  sublib
  some other libs like thrift)
```

In lib.cpp

```
Lib::process() {
    Sublib::process();
}
```

In sublib.cpp

```
void Sublib::process() {
...
}
```

I got errors like

Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
"Sublib::process()", reference from:
Sublib::process() in lib.cpp.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64

My question is, how do I make `Sublib::process()` visible to target test without having to link it to sublib like this? There are many other test targets that are already dependent on lib but not sublib.

```
add_executable(test test.cpp)
add_test(test test)
target_link_libraries(
  test
  lib
  sublib)
```

=======================================================================
With @VonC's suggestions, my files are updated this way:
project/lib/sublib/CMakeLists.txt

```
add_library(sublib OBJECT sublib.cpp)
target_link_libraries(
  sublib
  other_libs)

install(TARGETS sublib EXPORT sublib)
message (STATUS "Installed sublib")
install(EXPORT sublib
        FILE sublibConfig.cmake
        NAMESPACE sublib::
        DESTINATION lib/cmake/sublib)
```

project/lib/CMakeLists.txt

```
add_subdirectory(sublib)
find_package(iceberg CONFIG REQUIRED)
add_library(lib OBJECT lib.cpp)
target_include_directories(lib PUBLIC sublib::sublib)
target_link_libraries(
  lib
  PRIVATE other_libs
  PUBLIC sublib::sublib)
```

The CMake --build throws error:

```
-- Installed sublib
CMake Error at project/lib/CMakeLists.txt:21 (find_package):
  Could not find a package configuration file provided by "sublib" with any
  of the following names:

    sublibConfig.cmake
    sublib-config.cmake

  Add the installation prefix of "sublib" to CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH or set
  "sublib_DIR" to a directory containing one of the above files.  If
  "sublib" provides a separate development package or SDK, be sure it has
  been installed.


-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
See also "...project/cmake-build-debug/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".
See also "...project/cmake-build-debug/CMakeFiles/CMakeError.log".
```

The Cmake command

```
cmake --build /.../project/cmake-build-debug --target test -j 14
```

Is there anything wrong with my files?
Should I have 2 install() commands in sublib/CMakeLists.txt? Was the `FILE sublibConfig.cmake` name correct?

Comment: I see no top-level `CMakeLists.txt` in your tree. Does that mean that you firstly build the project `lib` (by using `cmake`, then `make`) and then build the project `test` (by using `cmake`, then `make`)? Or do you actually have a top-level `CMakeLists.txt`, which performs `add_subdirectory(lib)` and `add_subdirectory(test)`?

Comment: @Tsyvarev Thank you for looking! There is a top-level CMakeLists.txt, which has add_subdirectory(lib) and add_subdirectory(test). I updated the question description. What do you suggest?

Comment: Please remove the `makefile` tag from this question: this is a cmake question not a makefile question.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose the `undefined symbol` errors occurs because `test` target does not have direct visibility into the functions defined in `sublib`, even though `lib` links against `sublib`.
You would need to propagate `sublib`'s link interface to `lib`'s link interface, so that `test` can see `sublib`'s symbols through `lib`.

Use [`target_link_libraries()`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/target_link_libraries.html) with `PUBLIC` or `INTERFACE` keyword in `lib`'s `CMakeLists.txt` to specify that `sublib` is part of `lib`'s public interface.

```
# project/lib/CMakeLists.txt
add_subdirectory(sublib)

add_library(lib lib.cpp)
target_link_libraries(
  lib
  PUBLIC          # That is the key change
  sublib)
```

By setting `sublib` as a `PUBLIC` dependency of `lib`, you make sure any target that links against `lib` will also link against `sublib`, which should resolve the "undefined symbols" error.

---

> This doesn't work. The tests still cannot see the definitions in sublib. My CMakeLists file is `# project/lib/CMakeLists.txt add_subdirectory(sublib)  add_library(lib lib.cpp) target_link_libraries(   lib   PRIVATE other_libs PUBLIC sublib)`

Your CMakeLists file snippet seems to create a library (`lib`) and link it against another library (`sublib`) which is added through `add_subdirectory`.

In that case, you should try and specify the `include` directories using `target_include_directories` command.

```
add_subdirectory(sublib)
add_library(lib lib.cpp)
target_include_directories(lib PUBLIC sublib)
target_link_libraries(lib PRIVATE other_libs PUBLIC sublib)
```

And make sure `sublib` is properly exporting its targets, and that these are imported in the scope where `lib` is defined.

```
# In sublib/CMakeLists.txt
install(TARGETS sublib EXPORT SublibTargets)

# In lib/CMakeLists.txt
find_package(Sublib CONFIG REQUIRED)
```

Double-check `sublib`'s `CMakeLists.txt` file to make sure it is properly defining and exporting its targets and include directories.
Sometimes namespaces or incorrect target names can lead to issues. Make sure the target names and namespaces (if any) are correctly specified.

Use CMake's verbose output (`cmake --build . --verbose`) to obtain more information about what is happening during the build process.

---

> What should I use for the `EXPORT` name?
> In `lib/CMakelists.txt`, shall I call `find_package(sublib CONFIG REQUIRED)` first, or `add_library(lib ...)` first?

The `EXPORT` name is utilized to create a file that CMake can use to import the targets from `sublib`.
That name should match the name used in the `find_package()` command in `lib`'s `CMakeLists.txt` file.

The `EXPORT` name can be any valid identifier. For simplicity, it is often useful to use the name of the library, but this is not a strict requirement. In this case, `sublib` could be used as the `EXPORT` name.

```
install(TARGETS sublib EXPORT sublib)
```

In order to use `find_package(sublib CONFIG REQUIRED)` in `lib`'s `CMakeLists.txt`, a configuration file named `sublibConfig.cmake` or `sublib-config.cmake` should be generated and installed by `sublib`'s build. That can be accomplished using the [`install(EXPORT)` command](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/guide/tutorial/Adding%20Export%20Configuration.html).

```
install(EXPORT sublib
        FILE sublibTargets.cmake
        NAMESPACE sublib::
        DESTINATION lib/cmake/sublib)
```

The `sublibTargets.cmake` is a file that will be generated by CMake containing the exported targets.
The [`NAMESPACE` option](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/install.html#export) specifies a namespace for the exported targets, and the `DESTINATION` option specifies where to install the file.

The `find_package()` command should precede the `add_library()` command in `lib`'s `CMakeLists.txt`. That is because `find_package()` will import targets from `sublib`, which can then be used in subsequent commands such as `target_link_libraries()`.

```
find_package(sublib CONFIG REQUIRED)
add_library(lib lib.cpp)
target_link_libraries(lib PRIVATE other_libs PUBLIC sublib::sublib)
```

Note the usage of `sublib::sublib` in the `target_link_libraries()` command. That is the namespaced name of the `sublib` target, as specified by the `NAMESPACE` option in the `install(EXPORT)` command.

---

```bash
Could not find a package configuration file provided by "sublib" with any
  of the following names:

    sublibConfig.cmake
    sublib-config.cmake
```

Having two `install()` commands in `sublib/CMakeLists.txt` should be correct: The first `install(TARGETS sublib EXPORT sublib)` command installs the `sublib` target, while the second `install(EXPORT sublib ...)` command installs the export set that allows other projects to import `sublib`.

Make sure the `sublibConfig.cmake` file is being installed to the correct directory, and that this directory is being searched by CMake. The `DESTINATION lib/cmake/sublib` argument in your `install(EXPORT)` command in `sublib/CMakeLists.txt` specifies where the file will be installed.

The error message suggests adding the installation prefix of `sublib` to `CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH`. That can help CMake find the `sublibConfig.cmake` file.

```
list(APPEND CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH "${CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX}")
```

Insert that before the `find_package(sublib CONFIG REQUIRED)` command in your `lib/CMakeLists.txt`.

Or: you could set the `sublib_DIR` variable to point to the directory containing `sublibConfig.cmake`.

```
set(sublib_DIR "${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/sublib/lib/cmake/sublib")
find_package(sublib CONFIG REQUIRED)
```

(Adjust the path to the actual location of `sublibConfig.cmake`)

Inspect the `sublibConfig.cmake` file to make sure it is correctly generated and contains the necessary information to import the `sublib` target
The name `sublibConfig.cmake` in your `install(EXPORT)` command is correct, given that you are using `find_package(sublib CONFIG REQUIRED)` in `lib/CMakeLists.txt`.

Comment: thank you for your reply. But this doesn't work. The tests still cannot see the definitions in sublib. My CMakeLists file is

```# project/lib/CMakeLists.txt
add_subdirectory(sublib)

add_library(lib lib.cpp)
target_link_libraries(
  lib
  PRIVATE other_libs
PUBLIC sublib)
```

Comment: @user2577547 OK. I have edited the answer to address your comment.

Comment: I got the following errors: "CMake Error at project/lib/CMakeLists.txt:21 (find_package):
  Could not find a package configuration file provided by "sublib" with any
  of the following names:

    sublibConfig.cmake
    sublib-config.cmake
..."
sublib/CMakelists.txt

```
add_library(sublib sublib.cpp)
target_link_libraries(
  sublib
  other_libs)
install(TARGETS sublib EXPORT sublib)
message (STATUS "Installed sublib")
```
What should I use for the EXPORT name? In lib/CMakelists.txt, shall I call find_package(sublib CONFIG REQUIRED) first or add_library(lib ...) first?

Comment: @user2577547 I have edited the answer to address your comment.

Comment: It still doesn't work. I updated my question with the updated files content. Could you help take a look if I understood you correctly? Your help is very much appreciated!

Comment: @user2577547 I have edited the answer with some suggestions for you to check.